# i want to creating image tag system in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create image taging system in cakephp can any one say how i create data dictionary and how i handle relationship in cake ?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean tag system like in facebook see this example

A simple cake php tutorial to make simple photo album with photo tag like in face book

all tag function in tag.js & 'view,tag' functions in photos_controller

first you should run .sql on mysql

[Code](http://mhameen.blogspot.com/2010/05/simple-photo-album-using-cake-php.html)